# node.js upload image from ipad with socketio-file-upload

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm writing an app in express.js / node.js

I have a form with an input type "file" for upload images.

I want my images directly uploaded, without user confirmation. And displayed on the user screen after cropped and stored into a directory.

To do that, I use the socketio-file-upload library.

It works great on a computer. I can upload my images and display them.

The problem is with Ipad (I haven't try Iphone yet)

On the web app, when I click on the "browse" button, I can choose an existing picture or take a picture. I try to take a picture and upload it but nothing hapens...

Here is the code of the server for upload :

```
io.of('/register').on('connection', function (socket) {
/***************FILE UPLOAD***********************/
// Make an instance of socketioFileUploadServer and listen on this socket:
var uploader = new socketioFileUploadServer();
uploader.dir = __dirname + '/client/tmp/markers';
uploader.listen(socket);
// Do something when a file is saved:
uploader.on('saved', function(event){
    console.log('Original saved');
    // resize and rename image with a unique id
    var newName = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    // marker 32x32
    easyimg.rescrop({src:path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/tmp/markers/' + event.file.name), dst:path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/tmp/markers/' + newName + '_marker'), width:32, height:32}, function(err, image) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Resized and cropped: ' + image.width + ' x ' + image.height);
        // marker is uploaded - resized - croped, now display it
        socket.emit('displayMarker', {markerPath : '/tmp/markers/' + newName + '_marker', markerName : newName});
        // remove original from file system
        fs.unlink(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/tmp/markers/' + event.file.name), function(){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Original removed'); 
        });
    });
});

uploader.on('start', function(event){
    console.log('Client start upload');
    socket.emit('displayOverlay');
});

// Error handler:
uploader.on('error', function(event){
    console.log("Error from uploader", event);
});
});
```

And client side :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

// REGISTRATION MARKER 
var socketMarker    = io.connect('/register'); 
var siofuMarker     = new SocketIOFileUpload(socketMarker);

siofuMarker.listenOnInput(document.getElementById("uploadMarkerFromExploratorInput"));

// Do something when a file is uploaded:
siofuMarker.addEventListener("complete", function(event){
   $('.overlay').hide(); 
});

// display loader window
socketMarker.on('displayOverlay', displayOverlay);

// server send we can display the marker in the register step1 view
socketMarker.on('displayMarker', function(data) {
    $('#markerImage').html('');
    $('#markerImage').html('<img src="' + data.markerPath + '" />');
    $('#markerImageName').val(data.markerName);
});

});
```

With a computer, console will display :

```
Client start upload
Original saved
Resized and cropped: 32 x 32
Original removed
```

And with Ipad :

```
Client start upload
```

Is someone have a idea or another way to have the same result ?

Apreciate your help. C.

Comment: What does your markup look like for the input element?

Comment: Hi, I created a jsfiddle here : [http://jsfiddle.net/BStMd/](http://jsfiddle.net/BStMd/)

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, you need to add the proper attributes to the HTML markup for the File Input element:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

That should do the trick. The most important part to understand is the "accepts" attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your trick, I didn't know these parameters. Unfortunately, the result is the same ... works on a computer but not on Ipad

Comment: I tried with my Iphone (iOS 7.0.3 too) and ... it works !! Damn; it drives me crazy !

Comment: Hi, I need to implement a socket base image uploading function for iPhone/iPad, did your code manage to do it in the end?